# How can i see the Content of Flowfiles in queue via API in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a use case, where i have to see the content of each FlowFiles by calling the API.

API i have explored so far :

```
https://<URL>/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/<Queue-ID>/flowfiles/<FlowFile-UUID>/content
```

I got the response as below :

```
"The id of the node in the cluster is required."
```

Note : My NiFi is setting up in three node cluster.

Please suggest.

Comment: check how browser requesting it and just replicate this request in your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

*Hi Everyone, From below API, You'll get the content of flowfile which present in queue.

```
https://<URL>/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/<id>/flowfiles/<flowfile-uuid>/content?clusterNodeId=<clusterNodeId>
```